# LinkedIn returns 401 REST API when making request with HttpClient

Tags: linkedin-api

I am unable to retrieve the profile details when making a call the /people endpoint.

```
using(HttpClient client = new HttpClient())
  {
    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Authorization", "Bearer " + token.TempToken);
    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("x-li-format", "json");
    var response = await client.GetAsync("https://api.linkedin.com/v1/people/~?format=json");

    if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
    {
      return "success";
    }
    return "failed";
  }
```

I can confirm that the token is coming through at this point. And I have just successfully authorized before I pass the token to this code block.

Below is my request message:

> {Method: GET, RequestUri: 'https://api.linkedin.com/v1/people/~?format=json', Version: 1.1, Content: , Headers:
>   {
>     Authorization: Bearer AQTgH0PIdKoSnCbbDaFhubm2q3wJcmv-qvxOqcd42qbdzfDja4DUj5Cs0YMk6RZ37Gv_0WWsrv24C9vhOG7d8M3IlPS9fez9DjwNu37U71PLiTzGPN-I4j1FsY7aJeMmf9I1v_XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX_3ADwlS6_a9
>     x-li-format: json
>     x-ms-request-root-id: 388de07b-44400de197c25bd0
>     x-ms-request-id: |388de07b-44400de197c25bd0.1.
>     Request-Id: |388de07b-44400de197c25bd0.1.
>   }}

Any assistance would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same issue for a few hours on 21-June. Fortunately it resolved itself so I'm assuming a linkedin api problem.